# How to get code assist for HTML tag class attribute in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS for Spring application developement. I want to use Bootstrap CSS on frontend.

The problem is that code assist does not work for css classes (JetBrains PHPStorm is doing it just fine)

So when I type

```
<button class="|
```

I would like to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get list of all available css classes (obviously fetched from CSS files in project).

How can I do this?? Code assist for tags and  tag attributes works, but what about `class` attribute value?

[image: Here is my content assist config for HTML editor]

Comment: isn't ctrl+space the shortcut?

Comment: @DPM my bad - doing 10 things at once. I edited the shortcut

Comment: It looks to me like you'd need to roll your own content proposal assist plugin, if this is something that eclipse does not do. On a related note, this depends on the content assist whose configuration is under prefs->web->html files->editor->content assist

Comment: @DPM for clarification iv added screenshot. Indeed, looks like this feature is missing. I have tried this https://github.com/Enide/Eclipse-bootstrap-e4 but this does not work for me (no new options in content assist etc after installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required feature comes with plugin [wtp-web-resources](https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources) but it has some bugs and is no longer maintained because it was supposed to be merged into WTP as core feature and its not done yet.